# How can I change the color of AlertDialog title and the color of the line under it

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I changed the color of an AlertDialog title using this command

```
alert.setTitle( Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Set IP Address</font>"));
```

But I want to change the color of the line that appear under the title; how can I do that ?

Note: I don't want to use a custom layout

[image: screenshot of the desired effect]

Comment: is there a specific reason you are looking to avoid custom layouts? What additional stipulations do you have that need to be met?

Comment: You can actually change color of AlertDialog title by a very simple hack. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21401181/855884/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a particularly simple task to accomplish. [In my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171209/change-the-line-color-used-in-listseparatortextviewstyle/12172490#12172490), I detail how to adjust the color of a `ListSeparator` by just checking out the parent style used by Android, creating a new image, and creating a new style based on the original. Unfortunately, unlike with the `ListSeparator`'s style, `AlertDialog` themes are internal, and therefore cannot be referenced as parent styles. There is no easy way to change that little blue line! Thus you need to resort to making custom dialogs.

If that just isn't your cup of tea... **don't give up!** I was very disturbed that there was no easy way to do this so I set up a little project on github for making quickly customized holo-style dialogs (assuming that the phone supports the Holo style). **You can find the project here: https://github.com/danoz73/QustomDialog**

It should easily enable going from boring blue to exciting orange!

[image]

The project is basically an example of using a custom dialog builder, and in the example I created a custom view that seemed to cater to the IP Address example you give in your original question.

With `QustomDialog`, in order to create a basic dialog (title, message) with a desired different color for the title or divider, you use the following code:

```
private String HALLOWEEN_ORANGE = "#FF7F27";

QustomDialogBuilder qustomDialogBuilder = new QustomDialogBuilder(v.getContext()).
    setTitle("Set IP Address").
    setTitleColor(HALLOWEEN_ORANGE).
    setDividerColor(HALLOWEEN_ORANGE).
    setMessage("You are now entering the 10th dimension.");
        
qustomDialogBuilder.show();
```

And in order to add a custom layout (say, to add the little IP address `EditText`), you add

```
setCustomView(R.layout.example_ip_address_layout, v.getContext())
```

to the builder with a layout that you have designed (the IP example can be found in the github). [Many thanks to Joseph Earl and his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog/5392617#5392617).

Comment: why did android still not support changing the colors of alert dialog , should I use another dialog , or where is the problem?

Comment: Android is probably trying to enforce consistent UI patterns, so that is likely why this is so challenging. This is the best solution I could create to help you. I hope you find it useful, or at least interesting and informative :)

Comment: hello Daniel. thanks for sharing your work. It is quite helpful. I am facing one problem in implementing this. Actually I want to add single item choice using `setItems` in this custom dialog. When I add the list it actually shifts the title below the list. How to resolve this problem.

Comment: I have noticed this issue but haven't yet addressed it :-/ I will update when I have looked into it, but am really busy right now.

Comment: well, maybe not quite yet... I'm facing the problem of the title below the list... sorry.

Comment: dialog.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#f68122'>"+strtitle+"</font>"));

  Resources resources = dialog.getContext().getResources();
  int titleDividerId = resources.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
        View titleDivider = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerId);
        titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f68122"));

Comment: How to get custom view from the dialog ?

Comment: I'm also facing the problem of the title below the list after alertDialog.setAdapter() method

Comment: @DanielSmith hi! Good work, but did you find the solution for 'title below the list' as mentioned above

Answer (score 75):

**Divider color:**

It is a hack a bit, but it works great for me and it works without any external library (at least on Android 4.4).

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog)
       .setIcon(R.drawable.ic)
       .setMessage(R.string.dialog_msg);
//The tricky part
Dialog d = builder.show();
int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
```

You can find more dialog's ids in [alert_dialog.xml](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/4745ecc25a0a36c24e355ee3e6bd87f63b6a48c7%5E%5E%5E/sdk/platforms/android-16/data/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml) file. Eg. `android:id/alertTitle` for changing title color...

**UPDATE: Title color**

Hack for changing title color:

```
int textViewId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) d.findViewById(textViewId);
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
```

Comment: Even on KitKat I run into `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content` here.

Comment: I use this piece of code in many places in my app and everywhere it works fine. I only know about troubles with `DialogFragment` where title color hasn't id `android:id/alertTitle` but I didn't found the correct one.

Comment: @platzhirsch, in my custom DialogFragment class, I avoided the requestFeature() problem by running the customization code in onStart(). You can access the dialog there using getDialog().

Comment: @mmrmartin And do you have any ideas how to change the okay and cancel button background color?

Comment: Just as a heads up for future users that may come across this; for some reason, when I use just a generic Dialog I have to use "title" as my identifier name instead of "alertTitle". Not sure if this is mentioned anywhere else but just thought I would add my bit in hopes to help :P

Comment: i'm getting `NullPointerException` at the `setTextColor()`

Answer (score 21):

check this is *useful* for you...

```
public void setCustomTitle (View customTitleView)
```

you get detail from following link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCustomTitle%28android.view.View%29

CustomDialog.java

```
Dialog alert = new Dialog(this);
    alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alert.setContentView(R.layout.title);
    TextView msg = (TextView)alert.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    msg.setText("Hello Friends.\nIP address : 111.111.1.111");
    alert.show();
```

title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set IP address"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#775500"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

[image]

Comment: I try this but I still have the blue line under my TextView

Comment: i have some code. that put in answer after "Edit". you try this.

Answer (score 10):

This will set the color for the title, icon, and divider. Bound to change with any new Android version.

```
public static void colorAlertDialogTitle(AlertDialog dialog, int color) {
    int dividerId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    if (dividerId != 0) {
        View divider = dialog.findViewById(dividerId);
        divider.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    int textViewId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
    if (textViewId != 0) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(textViewId);
        tv.setTextColor(color);
    }

    int iconId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/icon", null, null);
    if (iconId != 0) {
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(iconId);
        icon.setColorFilter(color);
    }
}
```

Remember to call dialog.show() before calling this method.

Comment: @Vlado are you using appcompat? If so, this may not work.

Answer (score 9):

By following the [Dialog source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/Dialog.java), I found that Title is generated in Class [`MidWindow`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/MidWindow.java) by inflating the [`dialog_title_holo.xml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml) layout. so the Id of `mTitleView` is `title` and the Id of divider is `titleDivider`.

we can access to Id of `title` simply by `android.R.id.title`.

and access to Id of `titleDivider` by `Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("titleDivider","id", "android");`

The final code that i used to change the Direction of title and changing color is:

```
TextView mTitle = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.title);
mTitle.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
int x = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("titleDivider","id", "android");
View titleDivider = findViewById(x);
titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
```

Comment: This is a complete answer! Using android.R.id.title to change the title as well!

Comment: Great answer, helped me a lot! I had to change:
TextView mTitle = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.title); 
to:
TextView mTitle = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title); for this to work.

Comment: This one worked for me, I'm using an Activity that inherits @android:style/Theme.Dialog. Could customize the divider line and the title color. +1

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want a "library" for that, you can use this badly hack:

```
((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)) //ie LinearLayout containing all the dialog (title, titleDivider, content)
.getChildAt(1) // ie the view titleDivider
.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourBeautifulColor));
```

This was tested and work on 4.x; not tested under, but if my memory is good it should work for 2.x and 3.x

Comment: This works great for 4.x i haven't tried the others either so i will give them a try and confirm it

Comment: getDialog() gives me an error "The method getDialog() is undefined for the type MainActivity" it asks me to create a method

Answer (score 4):

In the class onCreateView, I put this:

```
Dialog d = getDialog();
    d.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#EC407A'>About</font>"));
    int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

colorPrimary links to our colors.xml file that stores all the colors. Also `d.setTitle` provides a hacky way to set the title colour.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution (based on suggested answers) that handles the styling of the dialogs in one class without needing to worry about the state of the dialog when you change the style - dialog can be already shown or just initialized.

Usage example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); //or builder.show()
DialogViewDecorator.decorate(dialog, android.R.color.holo_red_light); //can also set the defaut color in the class
```

Implementation:

```
public class DialogViewDecorator {

private static final
@ColorRes int DEFAULT_TITLE_DIVIDER_COLOR = android.R.color.holo_orange_light;

public static void decorate(Dialog dialog) {
    decorate(dialog, DEFAULT_TITLE_DIVIDER_COLOR);
}

/**
 * Sets the title divider color when the view is shown by setting DialogInterface.OnShowListener on the dialog.
 * <p/>
 * If you want to do other things onShow be sure to extend OnDecoratedDialogShownListener(call super.show(...)!)
 * and call {@link #decorate(Dialog, int, OnDecoratedDialogShownListener)}.
 *
 * @param dialog
 * @param titleDividerColor
 */
public static void decorate(Dialog dialog, final int titleDividerColor) {
    decorate(dialog, titleDividerColor, new OnDecoratedDialogShownListener(titleDividerColor));
}

/**
 * Method for setting a extended implementation of OnDecoratedDialogShownListener. Don't forget to call super
 * or the titleDividerColor wont be applied!
 *
 * @param dialog
 * @param titleDividerColor
 * @param OnShowListener
 * @param <T>
 */
public static <T extends OnDecoratedDialogShownListener> void decorate(Dialog dialog, int titleDividerColor, T OnShowListener) {
    if (dialog == null || titleDividerColor <= 0) { return; }

    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        setTitleDividerColor(dialog, titleDividerColor);
    } else {
        dialog.setOnShowListener(OnShowListener);
    }
}

private static void setTitleDividerColor(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int titleDividerColor) {
    try {
        Dialog dialog = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
        int dividerId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
        View divider = dialog.findViewById(dividerId);
        if (divider != null) {
            divider.setBackgroundColor(dialog.getContext().getResources().getColor(titleDividerColor));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static class OnDecoratedDialogShownListener implements DialogInterface.OnShowListener {
    private int titleDividerColor;

    public OnDecoratedDialogShownListener() {
        this.titleDividerColor = DEFAULT_TITLE_DIVIDER_COLOR;
    }

    public OnDecoratedDialogShownListener(int titleDividerColor) {
        this.titleDividerColor = titleDividerColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        setTitleDividerColor(dialogInterface, titleDividerColor);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating custom Layout for alert dialog

then you may add like this way easily to change the color

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DialogTitleBorder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/mExitDialogDesc"
    android:background="#4BBAE3"            <!--change color easily -->
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using **custom title layout** then you can use it like  `alertDialog.setCustomTitle(customTitle);`

**Example**

On UI thread use dialog like:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
 View customTitle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtitlebar, null);
 AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 d.setCustomTitle(customTitle);
 d.setMessage("Message");
 d.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
 d.show();
```

customtitlebar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#525f67">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customtitlebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Title Name"
        android:padding="3px"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" 
        android:layout_below="@id/icon"><!-- This is line below the title -->
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I want to change the color of the line inside the red ellipse

Answer (score 1):

```
    ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.agreement_popup_message);
    SpannableStringBuilder ssBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);
    ssBuilder.setSpan(
            foregroundColorSpan,
            0,
            title.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    );

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setTitle(ssBuilder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285514/1865860, I forked the nice github repo from @daniel-smith and made some improvements:

- improved example Activity
- improved layouts
- fixed `setItems` method
- added dividers into `items_list`
- dismiss dialogs on click
- support for disabled items in `setItems` methods
- `listItem` touch feedback
- scrollable dialog message

link: https://github.com/dentex/QustomDialog

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using divider in dialog, use the view in the custom layout and set the layout as custom layout in dialog.

custom_popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.divago.view.TextViewMedium
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="AlertDialog"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle"
        android:background="@color/txt_dark_grey" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/border"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <com.divago.view.TextViewRegular
            android:id="@+id/txtPopup"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity.java:

```
public void showPopUp(String title, String text) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup, null);

    TextView txtContent = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtPopup);
    txtContent.setText(text);

    TextView txtTitle = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtTitle.setText(title);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setView(alertLayout);
    alert.setCancelable(true);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using extending the dialog the use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```