# AlertDialog Holo accent color for styles.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I changed the colors of the SherlockActionBar using the Android Action Bar Style Generator.
I also changed the possible things with the Holo Colors Generator and all these styles work.

But when I get an AlertDialog in the PreferencesActivitiv(to change the settings), I still have the blue Holo accent. I found this link, which helps me to create a custom AlertDialogs:

[How can I change the color of AlertDialog title and the color of the line under it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under/15285514#15285514)

But i dont't know the attributes to set colors for the dialog in a theme. So that the dialogs are consistent in the whole app.

Answer (score 2):

there is a library which does exactly what you need:

https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Comment: This library helps me to make styled dialogs on android 2.2+. But it won't be change the dialog, which appears from the PreferencesActivity. 
After a lot of thinking, I decided to build my own preference screen with a FragmentList, so I could use your library. Thank you for your reply, even though it did not exactly answered my question :)

Comment: Yes you are right PreferenceActivity is pretty hard-coded in Android and there are lot of issues how to backport new stuff to older versions of Android. Your way is probably the easiest.