# Android Changing ListSperator

Tags: android, styles

I am getting this error:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.TextView.ListSeperator'.
```

I am trying to change the color of the ListSeperator.

Theme.xls

```
    <style name="customPrefCatListSeperator" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_list_section_divider</item>
    </style>

<style name="customPrefTextView" parent="customTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_green</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/customPrefCatListSeperator</item>
    </style>
```

Anyone find any solutions?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under if this help you just let us know here

Comment: that actually looks nice i may use that later, but I am using this with a preference category