# Android change color of dialog line

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I change the color of the line in a `Dialog` below:

[image: Dialog title divider]

Comment: why don't you create a custom dialog override the default dialog

Comment: @PrimeMinisterofIndia I did, can you please explain a bit more how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom layout, you can access to the divider `View` using `Resources.getIdentifier` after subclassing `AlertDialog` then calling `AlertDialog.findViewById`. Here's a quick example:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final CustomDialog cd = new CustomDialog(this);
    cd.setTitle("Title");
    cd.setMessage("Message");
    cd.show();
}

private static final class CustomDialog extends AlertDialog {

    private CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        final int id = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
        final View titleDivider = findViewById(id);
        if (titleDivider != null) {
            titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll have to inflate your own layout. Here's your answer:

[How can I change the color of AlertDialog title and the color of the line under it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under)

Answer (score 0):

create a custom AlertDialog and set custom title view using setCustomTitle.

```
 public AlertDialog.Builder setCustomTitle (View customTitleView)
```

Set the title using the custom view customTitleView. The methods setTitle(int) and setIcon(int) should be sufficient for most titles, but this is provided if the title needs more customization. Using this will replace the title and icon set via the other methods.

from this link.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCustomTitle%28android.view.View%29