# change title color of alertDialog on below android 5.0

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I had created an `AlertDialog` and wanted to change the title color of AlertDialog but getting failed in every attempt. It works very fine on `Android 5.0` and above with title color as black but when it runs below Android 5.0, it's title color get's changed to white, i had used style and many other sources from internet but failed, my code is as follows,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    final AppCompatDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setTitle("VALIDATION_TITLE error");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
```

My issue get's solved by following line,

```
dialog.setTitle( Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Set IP Address</font>"))
```

but i don't want to use this, anyhelp would be greatly appreciated. You can see the screenshot of my dialog from this [chat link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104538/discussion-between-vikram-singh-and-droidhacker)

Comment: create custom xml and set it on dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under

Comment: int PlateId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
  TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(PlateId);
   title.setTextColor(..   if this helps ?

Comment: @Dhina, no mate it's not working

Comment: the title is null is it ?

Comment: yes, it is, and thanks mate

Answer (score 5):

Use custom theme to customize alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
builder.setTitle("My Dialog");
builder.setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
       final AppCompatDialog dialog = builder.create();
       dialog.show();
```

**styles.xml - Custom style**

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogMaterialStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <!-- Used for the buttons -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_teal_900</item>
        <!-- Used for the title and text -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Used for the background -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: make sure that you are using 'AlertDialog' from support Lib. It should work.

Comment: Yes, it's  and this is my import file,  import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

Comment: i want a dialog as i am setting a corner radius programatically to the dialog,,so, i can't use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104538/discussion-between-vikram-singh-and-droidhacker).

Comment: make sure that you are extending AppCompatActivity with AppCompat theme. Then it should work. :)

Answer (score 3):

First type

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,
```

then type

```
android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialo
```

then <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then you will get some suggestion. You can select like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, 
  android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, 
  android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth);
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, 
  android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_NoActionBar);
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, 
  android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, 
  android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_DialogWhenLarge);
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Create custom view and set in dialoge using

dialog.setContentView(YOUR CUSTOM VIEW HERE);