# change the color of the title of a alertDialog when i'm using variable String

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-color, android-text-color

I just saw this post ([How can I change the color of AlertDialog title and the color of the line under it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under)) and I doubt if my title get a variable ... how I can use the first solution to change the color?

This is my code:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListadoBC.this);
   dialogo.setTitle("¡"+listaBC.get(arg2).getFragilidad()+" !\n"+"¿Ha seguido esta recomendación?");
```

And I want that this sentence `("¡"+listaBC.get(arg2).getFragilidad()+" !\n")` appears in red using something like this ()   `alert.setTitle( Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Set IP Address</font>"));`... is it possible?

Comment: Did you actually try `Html.fromHtml()` yet?

Comment: @Karakuri It is possible to do otherwise without creating a custom alertDialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Custom Dialog its possible, See below code.

```
Alert.setTitle(getHtmlFormatString("<font color='#FF7F27'>Set IP Address</font>");
```

getHtmlFormatString() is method to convert htmlTag to String.

```
 private Spanned getHtmlFormatString(String htmlTag)
{
    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        result = Html.fromHtml(htmlTag,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        result = Html.fromHtml(htmlTag);
    }
    return result;
}
```