# Why AlertDialog items color changed

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I was playing a bit with my styles.xml file and the theme editor. Now all my AlertDialogs are colored in red. I double checked the styles file and the theme editor on every single theme including parent themes and no items seem to be colored in red although in actual testing I still see the red color. Even tried making a specific theme for an AlertDialog and changing its primary and accent colors, but I still see the red dialog items.How can this happen ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please share the code as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the color of AlertDialog title and the color of the line under it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under)

Comment: Show your theme